# Solaris MQ accessing Message Hub in Bluemix via secure gateway

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mq, secure-gateway, message-hub

I'm testing to bridge messages from WMQ in Solaris to Message Hub - Bluemix and vice versa using Secure Gateway.

Since secure gateway client is not available for Solaris , what is the option for using secure gateway client in Solaris ?

Comment: Hello Vignesh! Could you add some more detail to this post? What is WMQ? Is this on the Solaris operating system? Does Solaris support Docker?

Comment: @Breedly  I'm pretty sure by WMQ he means IBM MQ which was formerly known as WebSphere MQ  (question has ibm-mq tag) .

Comment: Hello , Yes it is Websphere MQ or IBM MQ. Docker is not supported in Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vignesh, you are correct. The Secure Gateway team does not support Secure Gateway on Solaris. Unfortunately, you are on your own here.

If you are *desperate* to get this working you can unpack the .deb or .rpm packages and see if you can replicate the installation yourself, but translated for Solaris.

I would warn that I think this may also not be feasible as it looks like the application run time for Secure Gateway, NodeJS, may or may not be supported on Solaris.

Your best bet would be to run on Ubuntu, or RHEL if possible.

Comment: Thanks Breedly!! I installed a Docker version of Secure Gateway client  in a Linux Machine(B).. IBM MQ is on Solaris Machine(A).. Can MQ on System A  connect to Secure Gateway client on System B to expose the service to Message Hub in Bluemix ??